# Database lose data, cleaning?

Tags: database

I noticed that my database has lost 700Mb of data between two daily backup (between 14th and 15th of december) without any config change on our side.
I can't download them for the moment and compare them due to a bad internet connection.

Which kind of cleaning Craft CMS is doing ? What are the rules ?

Is it possible to list users activites ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Craft does do [garbage collection](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/gc.html).

It does have a small (configurable) change of running on every request, but someone can also force it via the CLI.

Maybe that’s what happened in your case?

Regardless, if you compare the dumps from the 14th and 15th with a diffing tool, you should be able to see where the size difference is coming from.